# What are some best practices for file/folder layout of large c++ project

Tags: c++, setup-project

Is it better to group files and folders by components or by file type ?

For example, lets say the project is the LibreOffice suite. Writer, Calc, Draw, etc.

should the folders be by component like this :

```
+ LibreOffice/
| + Writer/
|   + src/
|   + test/
| + Calc/
|   + src/
|   + test/
| + Draw/
|   + src/
|   + test/
```

Or by file type like this :

```
+ LibreOffice/
| + src/
|   + Writer/
|   + Calc/
|   + Draw/
| + include/
|   + Writer/
|   + Calc/
|   + Draw/
|-+ test/
|   + Writer/
|    ...
```

Comment: This is completely subjective.  The best way is the way you like.  If you're the first person on the project, you get to choose :)

Answer (score 2):

It is a matter of choice really.
But I usually follow the first method because that helps others understand the code layout in much better way by just an glance.
Always follow the practices and methods with which the next person working on your project shall find it easier to understand, for me the first method fits in to this appropriately.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I guess in hindsight it is more about preference.  I currently have a project that is laid out like choice 1.  But I find myself "cross cutting" often with things like build tools, unit test output tools, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would always go by component, file type even just sounds horrendously messy.

For example in a large web project I'd split up the scripts, stylesheets, references, images but also have things such as the classes required for my search functionality grouped together.

At a higher level I would split Data, Content, framework etc

Answer (score 0):

It really is a matter of choice. However, I prefer the first method and it seems to be the prominent choice among all answers.

A rationale argument would be that by choosing the first one, [build] scripts could perform all steps within all the (sub-)directory [Writer, Calc, Draw] without too much crawling around.

Also, new developers might find it easier to see all *relevant* files within the project sub-directories.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer choosing first option as that looks more logical and organized not only to me but to anyone who would work on this project in the future.

It also helps in a way that while debugging or doing any kind of source code analysis (lets say for "Writer"), the developer may be a looking for a specific text or pattern and thus needs to look into only files related to "Writer". While in second option, he has to browse through all the files (considering the worst case where the same pattern occurs in files related to "Writer"/"Calc"/"Draw" etc).

So, the life is much easier in first option.